# Power series expansion of $x\ln(\sqrt{4+x^2}-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, formal-power-series

> Find $a_n $ where $x \ln(\sqrt{4+x^2}-x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$.

I know that I must find power series expansion of $\ln(\sqrt{4+x^2})$ but it doesn't help. Can anyone give me a hint? many thanks

Comment: remember that $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

Comment: but what is $f^{n}(0)?$

Comment: it is the n-times derivative

Comment: for example, here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx+Ln%5B%E2%88%9A%284%2Bx%5E2%29-x%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+6%7D%5D%2F.%7Bx-%3E0%7D the 6-th derivative evaluated at the origin

Comment: "I know that I must find power series expansion of $\ln(\sqrt{4+x^2})$" Indeed this would not help at all.

Comment: @janmarqz Remembered. How does this help to solve the question?

Comment: @Did: $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2+\frac{f'''(0)}{6}x^3+\frac{f''''(0)}{24}x^4+\frac{f'''''(0)}{120}x^5+\frac{f''''''(0)}{720}x^6+\cdots$

Comment: @janmarqz And how to compute $f^{(1308)}(0)$, say? I suggest to think more seriously about a question before posting indications that are actually deadends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor $x$ can be momentarily disregarded; consider $f(x)=\ln(\sqrt{4+x^2}-x)$ and note that
$$
f'(x)=\frac{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}-1}{\sqrt{4+x^2}-x}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}=-\frac{1}{2}(1+(x/2)^2)^{-1/2}
$$
The Taylor development of the derivative can be written down. Integrate and multiply by $x$.
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{-1/2}{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n}}
$$
So
$$
f(x)=\ln2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{-1/2}{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^{2n}(2n+1)}
$$
I leave to you determining $a_n$.